# Arrow transition/transform and click link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to transition/transform my arrow from › (right) to ˇ (down) when on toggle. My problem is I don't know where to place it.

Also if you see on Menu 1 > Submenu 1 > Text with hyperlink

I want the '*Text with Hyperlink*' is clickable on the whole box(?) instead of just clicking the word itself.

I'm on my wit end. I have very little knowledge on this. I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you.

[This is actually what I tried to achieve - The arrow part and also the subitem is not strictly clickable on the word only (Menu > Submenu > Subitem)](https://codepen.io/knightray/pen/RwVoEKd)

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    var $this = $(this);
  
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Brandon Bold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.accordion {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}
ul li {
  margin: 0.3em 0;
}
ul li a.toggle {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.75em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
}
ul li a.toggle:hover {
  color: #fefefe;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 0.15em;
}

.subnotoggle {
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
}

.toggle::before {
  content: '\203A';
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.notoggle li {
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
}

.notoggle li a {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}

.notoggle li::before {
  content: '\2012';
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.notoggle li:hover::before {
  content: '\203A';
  font-size: 17px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Sub Menu 1</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <ul class="notoggle">
            <li><a href="#">Text with Hyperlink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text with Hyperlink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text with Hyperlink 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Sub Menu 2</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li class="subnotoggle">Sub Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Sub Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Another Sub</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li class="subnotoggle">Submenu 2</li>
      
      <li class="subnotoggle">Sub Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do it.

The combination of `position: relative` on a parent element, and `position: absolute` on a child element, is your friend. Much better control than faffing about with `float` and much easier to work with w.r.t. transforms/animations.

More powerful when you remember that a pseudo-element is a child element of the element it's spawned from, so you can position a pseudo-element absolutely within the bounds of a relatively positioned spawning element.

Hopefully this is roughly what you wanted. If you want the hover background colour change, just replicate it from the code you already have. All the ingredients are there.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    var $this = $(this);
    // we need to add a toggled class to the anchor that's clicked so we can mess with its pseudo-element:
    if ($this.hasClass('toggled')) {
      $this.removeClass('toggled') 
    } else { 
      $this.addClass('toggled'); 
    }
  
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Brandon Bold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.accordion {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}
ul li {
  margin: 0.3em 0;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.75em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
}
ul li a.toggle:hover {
  color: #fefefe;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 0.15em;
}

.subnotoggle {
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
}

.toggle::before {
  content: '\203A';
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: .2s transform;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.toggle.toggled::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.notoggle li {
  position: relative;
  /*
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575757;
  */
}

.notoggle li a {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}

.notoggle li::before {
  content: '\203A';
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: -15px;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: .2s transform;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.notoggle li:hover::before {
  content: '\203A';
  font-size: 17px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Sub Menu 1</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <ul class="notoggle">
            <li><a href="#">Text with Hyperlink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text with Hyperlink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text with Hyperlink 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Sub Menu 2</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li class="subnotoggle">Sub Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Sub Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Another Sub</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li class="subnotoggle">Submenu 2</li>
      
      <li class="subnotoggle">Sub Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```